# lcd.createChar() only allows for 8 custom characters

Tags: programming, lcd, c

I have a teensy4.1, with a 16 by 2 LCD screen, and an I2C LCD interface.
I was trying to write a bunch of custom characters to an LCD screen, to flip some text.

my issue is that it works fine, but on only up to 8 custom characters. any more than that produces odd results. with a loop of 16, the first 8 characters are printed. should more than 8 characters be defined, only the last assigned are in use.

I commented out all but the first 8 custom characters, and iterates through them in a loop of 16 iterations. this loops over the start. -- I guess that works as I would expect. If I define more than 8 custom Characters, only the last 8 assigned will output.

Here is a picture of that in action:
[image: customChar limits to 8]

here is my code:

```
#include <Adafruit_LiquidCrystal.h>
Adafruit_LiquidCrystal lcd(0);

//upside down char glyphs... default characters are 7x5 1 px w/space on the bottom
//these glyphs are 7x5 with space on the top 
byte uA[8] = {  B00000,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B11111,  B10001,  B10001,  B01110};
byte uB[8] = {  B00000,  B01111,  B10001,  B10001,  B01111,  B10001,  B10001,  B01111};
byte uC[8] = {  B00000,  B01110,  B10001,  B00001,  B00001,  B00001,  B10001,  B01110};
byte uD[8] = {  B00000,  B00111,  B01001,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B01001,  B00111};
byte uE[8] = {  B00000,  B11111,  B00001,  B00001,  B01111,  B00001,  B00001,  B11111};
byte uF[8] = {  B00000,  B00001,  B00001,  B00001,  B01111,  B00001,  B00001,  B11111};
byte uG[8] = {  B00000,  B11110,  B10001,  B10001,  B11101,  B00001,  B10001,  B01110};
byte uH[8] = {  B00000,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B11111,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001};
byte uI[8] = {  B00000,  B01110,  B00100,  B00100,  B00100,  B00100,  B00100,  B01110};
byte uJ[8] = {  B00000,  B00110,  B01001,  B01000,  B01000,  B01000,  B01000,  B11100};
byte uK[8] = {  B00000,  B10001,  B01001,  B00101,  B00011,  B00101,  B01001,  B10001};
byte uL[8] = {  B00000,  B01111,  B00001,  B00001,  B00001,  B00001,  B00001,  B00001};
byte uM[8] = {  B00000,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B10101,  B10101,  B11011,  B10001};
byte uN[8] = {  B00000,  B10001,  B10001,  B11001,  B10101,  B10011,  B10001,  B10001};
byte uO[8] = {  B00000,  B01110,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B01110};
byte uP[8] = {  B00000,  B00001,  B00001,  B00001,  B01111,  B10001,  B10001,  B01111};
byte uQ[8] = {  B00000,  B10110,  B01001,  B10101,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B01110};
byte uR[8] = {  B00000,  B10001,  B01001,  B00101,  B01111,  B10001,  B10001,  B01111};
byte uS[8] = {  B00000,  B01111,  B10000,  B10000,  B01110,  B00001,  B00001,  B11110};
byte uT[8] = {  B00000,  B00100,  B00100,  B00100,  B00100,  B00100,  B00100,  B11111};
byte uU[8] = {  B00000,  B01110,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001};
byte uV[8] = {  B00000,  B00100,  B01010,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001};
byte uW[8] = {  B00000,  B01010,  B10101,  B10101,  B10101,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001};
byte uX[8] = {  B00000,  B10001,  B10001,  B01010,  B00100,  B01010,  B10001,  B10001};
byte uY[8] = {  B00000,  B00100,  B00100,  B00100,  B01010,  B10001,  B10001,  B10001};
byte uZ[8] = {  B00000,  B11111,  B00001,  B00010,  B00100,  B01000,  B10000,  B11111};
//pockets
byte cornerA[]={B11111,B10000,B10000,B10000,B10000,B10000,B10000,B10000};//top left
byte cornerB[]={B10000,B10000,B10000,B10000,B10000,B10000,B10000,B11111};//btm left
byte cornerC[]={B11111,B00001,B00001,B00001,B00001,B00001,B00001,B00001};//top right
byte cornerD[]={B00001,B00001,B00001,B00001,B00001,B00001,B00001,B11111};//btm right
void flip(char *text);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16,2); // 
  //flipped characters
lcd.createChar(0,uA);
lcd.createChar(1,uB);
lcd.createChar(2,uC);
lcd.createChar(3,uD);
lcd.createChar(4,uE);
lcd.createChar(5,uF);
lcd.createChar(6,uG);
lcd.createChar(7,uH);
lcd.createChar(8,uI);
lcd.createChar(9,uJ);
lcd.createChar(10,uK);
lcd.createChar(11,uL);
lcd.createChar(12,uM);
lcd.createChar(13,uN);
lcd.createChar(14,uO);
lcd.createChar(15,uP);
/*lcd.createChar(16,uQ);
lcd.createChar(17,uR);
lcd.createChar(18,uS);
lcd.createChar(19,uT);
lcd.createChar(20,uU);
lcd.createChar(21,uV);
lcd.createChar(22,uW);
lcd.createChar(23,uX);
lcd.createChar(24,uY);
lcd.createChar(25,uZ);
lcd.createChar(26,cornerA);
lcd.createChar(27,cornerB);
lcd.createChar(28,cornerC);
lcd.createChar(29,cornerD);
*/
  //ascii coversion prolly like n+66
  //setCursor be like: (column, row) 16 cols, 2 rows, both start at 0
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  
  for (int i=0; i<16;i++){
  lcd.write(i); //prints ABCDEFGHABCDEFGH
  lcd.setCursor(i+1,0);
  delay (500);
  }
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("LIMIT 8 CHARS?");
}

void loop() {}
```

I would like to make more than 8 customChars, am I approaching this correctly? is there a limit somewhere I can change?

Comment: Note that some letters need not be flipped: `HINOSXZ`. For others, you could use lookalikes: `M` → `W`, `P` → `d`, `b` → `p`, `d` → `q`...

Comment: @EdgarBonet: And (depending on the character set in the particular device used) there may be other usable characters too. Most HD44780 displays have some katakana characters, so eg `E` → `ヨ` may also be usable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These displays only allow up to 8 custom defined characters. The hardware just only has the character RAM for at most 8 characters. They will be mapped to char codes 0 to 7 and 8 to 15. The character code 8 always prints the same character as code 0, 9 as 1 and so on.

So no, there is no way to use more than 8 custom characters *at once*. Of course, you can change the characters dynamically, so that a certain location of the screen always shows a changing custom character icon.

Comment: Bloody hell, its in the datasheet. I tried modding the library first, and that did not work. 
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/HD44780.pdf

Comment: Yea, you can modify the library, but you can't modify the hardware...